# Телеграм бот не пересылает сообщения в группу

Tags: python-telegram-bot

```
from settings import _token, my_group_id
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext


TOKEN = _token
GROUP_CHAT_ID = my_group_id
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Сообщения будут пересылаться в группу')

def forward_to_group(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    context.bot.forward_message(chat_id=GROUP_CHAT_ID, from_chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, forward_to_group))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Желательно с использованием именно этой библиотеки, так как на ней написан весь остальной проект. После долгих попыток внедрить этот функционал в свой код создал я отдельно скрипт для пересылания одного сообщения, но всё равно безуспешно. Боту выдал ВСЕ права, chat_id проверил несколько раз. И всё равно получаю ошибку "telegram.error.BadRequest: Chat not found"